# Having Problems with $.json in Ember

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

I am trying to use $.getJSON with Ember.js (Basically I am trying to avoid Ember-Data). Here's my code,

```
App = Ember.Application.Create();

App.Model = Ember.Object.extend({

});

App.Users = App.Model.extend({
    id: null,
    name: null
});


App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.Users.findAll();
    }
});

App.Users.reopenClass({
  findAll: function() {
    var result = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({content: []});

    $.getJSON('user.php', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(i, row) {
        result.pushObject(App.Users.create(row));
      });
    });

    return result;
  }
});
```

and Here's my HTML:

```
<body>
        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="MyTemplate">


            {{#each item in controller }}
            <tr><td>
             <p> {{item.name}}</p>
            </td></tr>
            {{/each}}

        </script>

        <script type="text/x-handlebars">
            <h1>Application Template</h1>
            {{outlet}}
        </script>

    </body>
```

Issue I am having is it is not the loading the model, do I need an controller too?  Or anything else I am missing on my part?

Comment: `create` has a lower-case c. Class names start with capital letters. Methods and instances start with lower-case letters.

Comment: Thanks! I am such a noob :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have a small typo at the creation of the Application.

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
```

PS: Your code looks fine. Only the router mapping is missing, but i guess you left that one intentionally out of your example.

**Update:**

You should define a mapping for your `UsersRoute`:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("users", { path: "/users" });
});
```

Your Template should be named accordingly as `users`:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="users">


            {{#each item in controller }}
            <tr><td>
             <p> {{item.name}}</p>
            </td></tr>
            {{/each}}

        </script>
```

And finally you should create a link to your Route in the main application template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h1>Application Template</h1>
  {{outlet}}
  {{#linkTo "users"}} Link to UsersRoute{{/linkTo}}
</script>
```

Comment: I have edited my question now, so I guess I am missing router mapping.

Comment: I am little confused about Template name, how should we decide the template name?

Comment: In this case this is pretty easy. You deal with users. So you want a UsersRoute, a UsersController, a UsersView and a template named accordingly, so 'users' :-)

Comment: In your case the Controller and View have been automatically generated by Ember. Ember finds your UsersRoute and creates a UsersView, which expects the template named 'users'.

Comment: One more question, if want to load user on page load what changes I can make?

Comment: What do you mean by `load user on page load`? You want to enter the users Route automatically?

Comment: yeah, I want to load that route automatically.

Comment: I guess I have make changes in IndexRoute right? Like this, http://pastebin.com/9YB748rq

Comment: Yeah the IndexRoute is the right place. Have a look at the Ember Api Docs. There is a method called redirect, which you can implement. I am out for lunch, so i cant show you right now :-)